# Migrate to Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

We've got a new server with TFS installed. The current environment is very usual, source code managed with SourceSafe 2005 and integrated with Visual Studio 2008 Enterprise Edition. The QA team is using Bugzilla to report the bugs.

First of all some basic questions:

1. How can I move my project to *TFS*
   along with the database which is on
   *SQL Server 2005*?
2. Will the use of *SourceSafe* remain there or
   *TFS* provides other way to manage
   your source?
3. All client machines (*Visual Studio 2008*) will have to integrate with
   *TFS*, How?
4. Is *TFS* provides a tool for Bug
   Tracking/Reporting? If yes, what
   should we do to move from *Bugzilla*
   to *TFS*? If a Bug Tracking/Reporting
   tool exists, as a consequences there
   will be a different approach required for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can migrate SourceSafe to TFS using [this tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253060(VS.80).aspx).
2. TFS provides source control capabilities so after migrating you no longer would need to use SourceSafe.
3. You install the Team Explorer client to integrate Visual Studio with TFS.
4. TFS does also include bug tracking/reporting capabilities.  You can check out [this tool](http://migrationsynctoolkit.codeplex.com/) for migrating Bugzilla to TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is also a web-client for TFS 2008, TeamSystem Web Access, which will be incorporated in the total install in the next TFS 2010.
So even external clients or project managers can read and modify bugs/work items without installing VisualStudio.

If you use this, be sure to also install the sp1 (and hotfix)